# Windows 8 apps (Xaml, C#) Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Is it possible to embed a WebView and load Google Maps in it with push-pins loaded in the map for a set of co-ordinates? I'm using Xaml and C# for Windows 8 applications.